# Validity of basic train - test - split for a time series using a RNN

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, train-test-split

I am trying to determine if a simple train-test-split is valid for a time series if I  use  a Recurrent Neural Network (LSTM). Lets say I have  samples (x) which consist of 2 days values (time steps) and the y variable represents the day after (ie. I have day 1 and 2 as one of the x samples and want to predict day 3 (y)). In this situation, do we need to make a train test split based on dates, or I can just do the basic split since the RNN will have as input always the 2 days prior the one I am trying to predict? I trained using the simple split and got better results than using date related split, so I am trying to check if I am not "lying" myself doing the wrong split. I know that common time series techniques need to split acording to dates but I am unsure if a RNN does to.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should respect the time order while splitting the dataset. This is simply because you're also peeking into the future for other samples in the learning process.

To give a simple illustration, let's say you've the following training samples:

```
b,c,d --> e
c,d,e --> f
```

while trying to estimate `f` from `c,d,e` you also learn some relationship between `c,d,e`. And, the algorithm can use this knowledge embedded somewhere in the architecture to generate better guesses from `b,c,d` to `e`, since it already knows something between `c,d,e`.

Comment: Acording to your example, if I had also on the train sample e,f,g->h (after sample 1 and 2, so train set is time ordered ) but I test the model on d,e,f->g, I will be "cheating" because  I used a sample for the train that was ahead in time regarding the test sample I am evaluating ? On another side, what if I use features instead the time series to predict the y values, would it be ok the normal  random split, unless those features were autocorrelated (those feature would be a time series also since I got them for each day)

Comment: That is right. You peek into future trends during training.

Comment: @JmML sorry, I didn't see your edited comment. For your second question, the principle is simple, if there is temporal dependency between the features, you need to respect that.